# Linphone - libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, linphone, linphone-sdk

So im building a Voip app using linphone SDK. It builded nicely and it runs fine on the simulator and real device, but when I login with my SIP account, close the app and ty to open it again, the app crashs @ the Launchscreen and freezes.

Here is the error i get:

```
2016-10-11 14:50:40.093 linphone[25577:75140] Crash: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
2016-10-11 14:50:40.094 linphone[25577:75140] Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d1934b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011077a21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c293b3 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c305c4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   linphone                            0x000000010aa6c3de -[InAppProductsManager callXmlrpcRequestWithParams:onSuccess:onError:extra:] + 542
    5   linphone                            0x000000010aa6be2e -[InAppProductsManager checkAccountExpirationDate] + 158
    6   linphone                            0x000000010aa67a37 -[InAppProductsManager init] + 599
    7   linphone                            0x000000010aa26fd7 -[LinphoneManager startLinphoneCore] + 199
    8   linphone                            0x000000010a9c4693 -[LinphoneAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 563
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ec8168e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ec83013 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ec893b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ec86539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011565476b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001156545e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011565496d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110cbe311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca359c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca2a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca2494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010ec84db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010ec8af34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  linphone                            0x000000010a9c2ebe main + 126
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011167b68d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7
)
2016-10-11 14:50:40.113 linphone[25577:75140] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d1934b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011077a21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c293b3 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c305c4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   linphone                            0x000000010aa6c3de -[InAppProductsManager callXmlrpcRequestWithParams:onSuccess:onError:extra:] + 542
    5   linphone                            0x000000010aa6be2e -[InAppProductsManager checkAccountExpirationDate] + 158
    6   linphone                            0x000000010aa67a37 -[InAppProductsManager init] + 599
    7   linphone                            0x000000010aa26fd7 -[LinphoneManager startLinphoneCore] + 199
    8   linphone                            0x000000010a9c4693 -[LinphoneAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 563
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ec8168e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ec83013 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ec893b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ec86539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011565476b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001156545e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011565496d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110cbe311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca359c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca2a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ca2494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010ec84db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010ec8af34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  linphone                            0x000000010a9c2ebe main + 126
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011167b68d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any ideas on what the error is? 
Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: What does the code for `callXmlrpcRequestWithParams:onSuccess:onError:extra:` look like?  (Specifically, anyplace it calls `arrayWithObjects:count:`.)

Comment: @PhillipMills Posted as a answer cause the code is too big.

Comment: Since the error is complaining about the object at offset [1], I'll guess that `password` is nil.